# Get Object's Parent Without Using Loops in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way/function(s) in lodash to get the object's parent of a particular pet id without having to write code that would loop over each person/pet?

For example: `_.getParent(people, pets.id => 11) // returns {"type":"Fish", "id":11}`.

```
let people = [
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "pets": [
            { "type":"Frog", "id":23 },
            { "type":"Bird", "id":57 },
            { "type":"Fish", "id":11 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Dawn",
        "pets": [
            { "type":"Lion", "id":89 },
            { "type":"Duck", "id":51 }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Anne"
    },
    {
        "name": "Josh",
        "pets": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Not to blow your mind, but lodash uses loops behind the scenes. :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yup, I know that. My `people` object is fairly complex (and nested) and I want to find a way to utilize lodash to clean up my code. I already have a solution that uses multiple `_.forEach` to find the pet id.

Comment: perhaps something like: ```let peopleWithPets = people.filter(person => person.pet && person.pet.length); let peopleWithFish = peopleWithPets.filter(person => person.pets.filter(pet => pet.id == 11).length)``` you could use lodash's ```find``` instead of ```filter``` which will exit the loop as soon as an entry matching the criteria is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
_.filter(
    _.flatMap(people, 'pets'),
    t => t && t.id === 11
)
```